# Raspberry Pi sending same data?

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, pygame, uart

So I am using Pygame to create a display for an quadrature encoder counter. I am using [EzText](https://github.com/ffavela/eztext) to prompt a user input on the display where I can change the maximum count and send updated value via UART to the microcontroller that is in charge of doing the actual counting. Here is my code (sorry for the length, I marked the part that deals with the user input towards the bottom):

```
import sys, serial, string, pygame, eztext
import pygame.locals as GAME_GLOBALS
import pygame.event as GAME_EVENTS

windowWidth = 1680
windowHeight = 1050
maxCount New = 32767
posDataStr = " "
rect1 = (1000,350,290,75)
rect2 = (1000,555,290,75)

black = (0,0,0)
white = (248,248,255_

pygame.init()
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth,windowHeight), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
background = pygame.image.load("/home/pi/MyProjects/background.png")
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",96,1)
surface.blit(background, (0,0))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)    #hide mouse pointer

def quitGame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

DEVICE = "/dev/ttyAMA0"
ser = serial.Serial(DEVICE, 19200)

#draw Max Count rectangles
pygame.draw.rect(surface, (black), (995,550,300,85))
pygame.draw.rect(surface, (white), (1000,555,290,75))

# draw current count background (black) rectangle (since it doesn't need to update)
pygame.draw.rect(surface, (black), (995,345,300,85))

#draw maxCountNew as text
maxCountText = myFont.render(str(maxCountNew), 1, (black))
surface.blit(maxCountText, (1000,545))

pygame.display.update()

while True:

    posData = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    
    i = ser.read()
    if i == '*':
        for x in range (0,6):
            posData[x] = ser.read()
            if posData[x] == ',' or posData[x] == '\00'
                del posData[x:]
                posDataStr = ''.join(posData)
                break

    #draw posDataStr rectangles
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (white), (1000,350,290,75))

    #draw currentCountStr as text
    currentCountText = myFont.render(posDataStr,1,(black))
    surface.blit(currentCountText, (1000,340))

    for event in GAME_EVENTS.get():

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                quitGame()

###################################################################################################
#THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC SECTION (I think)


            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                txtbx = eztext.Input(maxlength=5,color=black,prompt='Enter New Resolution: ')
                
                while True:

                    events = pygame.event.get()

                    #blit txtbx on the screen
                    txtbx.draw(surface)

                    #update txtbx
                    txtbx.update(events)

                    #refresh the display
                    pygame.display.flip()

                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        break
                    if len(txtbx.value) > 4:  #once 5 digits are entered
                        break

                newMax = txtbx.value

                #write new position to MCU
                ser.write(newMax.encode())
                print newMax.encode()      //for diagnostic purposes

                #max count is resolution - 1
                maxCountNewInt = int(newMax) - 1

                #convert back to a string
                maxCountNew = str(maxCountNewInt)

                #refresh the display
                surface.blit(background, (0,0))
                pygame.draw.rect(surface,(white),(1000,555,290,75))
                maxCountText = myFont.render(maxCountNew, 1, (black)) #display new max count txt
                surface.blit(maxCountText, (1000,545))
                pygame.display.update()

    pygame.display.update(rect1)
    pygame.display.update(rect2)
```

When I enter a value using the EzText prompt, the value entered is saved correctly into the newMax variable. The first time I send the data to my microcontroller, I get the correct value. On subsequent inputs on the RasPi, the newMax variable is adjusted correctly but the same value as the first time is sent to the microcontroller. Am I using ser.write() incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do `txtbx.value = ""`?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post. I did a little more diagnosing (including your recommendation) and it looks like the txtbx.value is being updated correctly but the serial data being sent is incorrect.